# Content Delivery Network

Tags: dns, failover, geoip, cdn

I have a project that i need to setup **Content Delivery Network** on Ubuntu, That involves like **Geo Dns structure, Fail over and High availability**

So i am looking if some one help me that where should i start, I have no experience about it, so i would like if some help me with good links **OR** how to configure it ( step by step )

Comment: Are you talking about setting up your own, private, geographically distributed servers, or using a third party service, like Cloudflare? What have you tried so far? Please elaborate on your question. Available servers? System specs?, amount of content to be moved?, and to where, etc.

Comment: Yes i am planning to setup my own CDN... no third party

Comment: Servers are in US, UK, Netherlands